# Google.Load ['table'] does nothing in Chrome content-script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-visualization, content-script

I am creating a `Chrome Extension` that utilises a `content-script` to insert a [Google Visualisation Table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) into a page once it has finished loading. The problem though is that the table is never displayed - it is also not in the html as can be seen from the images below.

Manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "blah",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*"
    ],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
        "jquery-1.10.2.min.map"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.ebay.co.uk/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.10.2.min.js", "jsapi.js", "myScript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

MyScript.js

```
$('#cbrt').after('<div id=\'google_table_div\'></div>');

google.load('visualization', '1', { packages:['table'], callback : function() { drawTable(); } });

function drawTable() 
{
    alert('draw');
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
    data.addRows([
        ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
        ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
        ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
        ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('google_table_div'));
    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true}); 
}
```

The `alert` in the callback never happens. Here is the HTML at the end:
[image: head]
[image: body]

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the 'table' package as well.  Like so:

```
packages:['corechart', 'table']
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo (from trying to load other controls when I was trying to get it to work). It doesn't work with `packages:['table']`

Comment: Your code runs fine on its own, when the google.load() call occurs as the page is being loaded.  Perhaps your problem is related to not calling google.load() as the page is being loaded, but I don't know why.  The 'deferred' mode is used when you have a 'callback' option, but it seems the callback function is never called (so your alert never shows up).  Are there any errors in your javascript console?